# Shifting of edges between edge-disjoint matchings in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. If $M$ and $N$ are two disjoint matchings $(M\cap N = \emptyset)$ 
in $G$ with $|M| > |N|$, then there are disjoint matchings $M_1$ and $N_1$ such that 
$|M_1| = |M| - 1$, $|N_1| = |N| + 1$, and $M_1\cup N_1 = M\cup N$.

I'm having trouble with this problem because while I understand that we're shifting edges between the two matchings, I have no idea how to prove that can be done.

Comment: Can we just put an edge in M to N?

Comment: @mathpadawan, that's what I was wondering, but that does not sound like a proof. Also, would simply moving an edge from M to N ensure that $N_1$ is still a matching? Because even though they are M and N are edge-disjoint, they could still share a vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the union $M \cup N$ of the two matchings.

This is a set of edges forming a subgraph of $G$ in which every vertex has maximum degree $2$. More precisely, every vertex is incident to at most one edge from each matching. You might imagine coloring the edges of $M$ red and the edges of $N$ blue; every vertex is incident to a red edge, or a blue edge, or neither, or both.

So what can the connected components of this subgraph look like? (First think about what kinds of connected graphs have maximum degree $2$, and then about what the colors on the edges will be for each kind.)

What kind of component can you use to increase the size of $N$ (and decrease the size of $M$)? And how can you argue that such a component must exist?

Comment: I'm fairly new to mathematical proofs so my questions might have obvious answers. What you're saying is that to solve this question I'll have four cases to demonstrate? Or from the options you listed at the end of that first paragraph I just show the one needed?

Comment: You have four cases to consider for the vertices - and all of them are possible - but you should think about what the connected components (which consist of several vertices) could be like.

Comment: So as far as I see, my options are cycles, trees, and just any 2-connected graph. What I see is that with a tree, given that $M = blue$ is bigger than $N = red$, this tree will start and end with blue. So there'll be one more $M$, than $N$. But I don't see how I can give one edge in M to N without simply just inverting M and N. Same thing with a cycle, how would I take an edge from M and give it to N without having to change of the subsequent edges and thereby inverting the matchings.

Comment: Well, first of all, "trees and 2-connected graphs" is too general: your only option is paths. Second, why not just invert M and N (on one of these components)?

Comment: I'm not saying I can't invert them, my only question with doing that is does it count as sufficient proof? Also, I'm not sure how to be more specific than trees. Is there a specific example you can give me?

Comment: The only trees with maximum degree 2 are paths. Anything else has a vertex of degree 3 or more. And inverting a component with $k+1$ edges from $M$ and $k$ edges from $N$ is perfectly fine as a step in your proof - the one thing you have to check is that there *is* some such component.

Comment: I can't think of anything, could you give me an example of a graph with maximum degree 2 that is not a path? The only other thing I can think of is cycles, but that wouldn't work in this question.

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. I'm telling you that there are *no* such graphs other than paths or cycles, so there are none of the things you want an example of.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were telling me that there were, and that's what I was trying to figure out. Thank you, I understand now.